# A consequence of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Riemann Lebesgue lemma states that: For a function $f\in L_1([-\pi,\pi])$ we have 
\begin{align}
\lim_{|n|\to \infty}  \int_{[-\pi,\pi]} f(t) e^{-int} \text{ d}t =0.
\end{align}
The integral here is Lebesuge integral. As consequences of this lemma, 
\begin{align}
\lim_{|n|\to \infty} \int_{[-\pi,\pi]} f(t) \cos(nt) \text{ d}t =0 ,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\lim_{|n|\to \infty} \int_{[-\pi,\pi]} f(t) \sin(nt) \text{ d}t = 0.
\end{align}
How to prove these two corollaries. I need any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which corollaries, did You omit $...=0$ and do You know Euler's formula $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ ?

Comment: I know Euler`s identity. Using it gives $\int_{[-\pi,\pi]} f(t) \cos(nt) dt - i \int_{[-\pi,\pi]} f(t) \sin(nt) dt \to 0$ as $|n|\to \infty$.

Comment: Apply it to $e^{it}$ since the limit is 0, both real and imaginary parts converges to 0

Comment: Well then $\int_{-\pi,\pi}f(t)e^{-int}=\int_{-\pi,\pi}f(t)\cos(nt)dt-i\int_{-\pi,\pi}f(t)\sin(nt)dt$

Comment: How do you know that $\int_{[-\pi,\pi]} f(t) \cos(nt) \text{ d}t$ and $\int_{[-\pi,\pi]} f(t) \sin(nt) \text{ d}t$ are both real? @HAMIDINESOUMARE

Comment: I supposed $f$ to be real valued, isn't it?

Comment: No, $f$ in my textbook may be real or complex-valued function.

Comment: Ok. $f$ is real, isn’t it? $\sin(nt)$ too. Have you ever seen an integral of real valued functions giving a ( strictly) complex function?

Comment: I think the problem here is that the textbook generally considers complex valued functions, but I'm pretty sure that $f$ is assumed to be real valued here, otherwise You don't get these corollaries I guess.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $\lim_{|n|\rightarrow\infty}\int f e^{inx}dx = 0$ gives
$$
   \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int f e^{inx}dx = 0 \\
   \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int f e^{-inx}dx = 0
$$
Adding these results in
$$
         \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int f \cos(nx)dx = 0
$$
I'll let you tackle the other combinations.